# C# Chart Y axis grid and label scrolling

Tags: c#

I'm struggling with MS C# chart display and Y axis scrolling.
What i want to do is that when i slide the Y axis scrollbar, the major grid slide too. But the major grid is fixed and the Label change.
The Y axis is "number style".
The X axis is a "datetime style".
When i scroll the X-axis, the Date scroll too. This is well synchronized.
But this is not the case for the Y axis.
I have try to modify the YAxis.LabelStyle and YAxis.MajorGrid without success.

[Y axis label description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtLsm.png)

Below is the source code for this question.

```
        // Create new Graph
        chart = new Graph.Chart();
        // Définition de la taille et du modèle de chart
        chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 700);
        chart.BackGradientStyle = Graph.GradientStyle.LeftRight;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = Graph.BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        // Add a chartarea called "draw", add axes to it and color the area black
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("draw");

        // Définition axe X (secondes). Largeur 200s, interval = 10s, label toutes les 30s
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Interval = 10;   // Ajoute une trait à chaque interval de 10s sur l'axe (attention, c'est différent de la grille !!!)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Title = "Temps";
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 30;    // Ajoute un label toutes les 30s
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm:ss";
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Minimum = 0; // En nombre de jour ! (pourquoi, je sais pas)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Maximum = 200.0/(24.0*60*60.0); // En nombre de jour ! Donc 200s => 200s / (24h*60m*60s)

        // Définition grille axe X . Interval tous les 10s, lignes tirets blancs
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 10;   // 10s entre chaque graduation (grille traversant l'axe X verticalement)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        // Définition axe Y (nombre). Min = -0.4 Max = 1 Interval = 0.2
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum = -0.4;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval = 0.2;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.1;    // Ajoute un label tous les 0.1
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = ".000";

        // Définition grille axe Y . Interval tous les 0.1, lignes tirets blancs
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 0.1;   // 1 entre chaque graduation (grille traversant l'axe Y horizontalement)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        // Définition grille axe secondaire Y . Lignes pointillées
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dot;

        // Couleur de fond du tracé
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].BackColor = Color.Black;

        // Create two new functions series
        chart.Series.Add("MyFunc");
        chart.Series.Add("MyFunc2");
        // Set the type to line      
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;

        // Ajouter un tooltip sur la valeur pointée
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].ToolTip = "#VAL";
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].ToolTip = "#VAL";

        // Color the line of the graph light green and give it a thickness of 3
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].Color = Color.LightGreen;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].Color = Color.Bisque;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].BorderWidth = 3;

        // Définition des types de données sur les axes X et Y des séries de données
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].XValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].YValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.Double;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].XAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].YAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].XValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].YValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.Double;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].XAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].YAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Secondary;

        //This function cannot include zero, and we walk through it in steps of 0.1 to add coordinates to our series
        DateTime dto;
        dto = new DateTime();
        for (double x = 0.1; x < 20; x += 0.1)
        {
            chart.Series["MyFunc"].Points.AddXY(dto, Math.Sin(x) / x);
            chart.Series["MyFunc2"].Points.AddXY(dto, Math.Cos(x) / x);
            dto = dto.AddSeconds(1);
        }

        // Ajout des légendes
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].LegendText = "sin(x) / x";
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].LegendText = "cos(x) / x";

        // Create a new legend called "MyLegend".
        chart.Legends.Add("MyLegend");
        chart.Legends["MyLegend"].BorderColor = Color.Tomato; // I like tomato juice!

        // Autorisation de zoomer
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        // Définition des curseurs en X et Y afin de pouvoir sélectionner la zone à zoomer
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.Interval = 0.001;  // Valeur minimum sélectionnable par l'utilisateur (on ne peut pas zoomer au delà)

        // Définition des mises à l'échelles et des barres de défilements axe X et Y
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;

        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSize = 0.1D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0.001D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

        //chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = false;

        // Couleur des scrollbars
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightBlue;

        // On ajoute à la form le chart (sinon, on ne sait pas ou l'afficher !)
        Controls.Add(this.chart);
    }
```

Do you have any idea to do this.
It works well for X axis without any code, but not for Y axis.
I think it's possible to do something with AxisChanged event, but quite tricky.
I hope my question is clear ! English is not my favourite language !

Comment: NB: I use Visual Studio 2015 and Framework 4.0

Comment: I noticed this `chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval = 0.2;` Where you specify the interval of YAxis. The label depends on it.

Comment: Hi WagoL, i have suppressed chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval = 0.2; in the source code. The result is the same as with the line. I try to solve the problem with AxisViewChanged event (without success)

Answer (score 0):

Some update to my problem.

I have added an event handler on AxisViewChanged.
In this event handler i update the label, grid and interval on Y axis depending on the AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum value.

This event handler also resize the secondary axis regarding the zoom on Y axis.

```
        Graph.Chart chart;
    double MaxY2;
    double MinY2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(750, 750);

        // Create new Graph
        chart = new Graph.Chart();
        // Define size and chart model
        chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 700);
        chart.BackGradientStyle = Graph.GradientStyle.LeftRight;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = Graph.BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        // Add a chartarea called "draw", add axes to it and color the area black
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("draw");

        // Define X axis interval type (seconds). Width 200s, interval = 10s, label every 30s
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Interval = 10;   // Add a tick every 10s interval on X axis (careful, it's different from the grid !!!)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Title = "Time (s)";
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 30;    // Add a label every 30s
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm:ss";
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Minimum = 0; // X axis unit is a day ! (don't know why )
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.Maximum = 200.0/(24.0*60.0*60.0); // Unit is a day so convert second in day unit =>  200s => 200s / (24h*60m*60s)

        // X Axis grid definition. Interval every 10s, dash line
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 10;   // 10s between each tick (grid cross X axis vertically)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        // Y axis definition (number). Min = -0.4 Max = 1 Interval = 0.2
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum = -0.4;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval = 0.2;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.1;    // Add a label every 0.1
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = ".000";

        // Secondary Y axis definition (number). Min = -2 Max = 10 Interval = 0.5
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum = -2;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Maximum = 10;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Interval = 0.5;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.5;    // Add a label every 0.5
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Format = ".000";

        // Y Axis grid definition. Interval every 0.1, dash line
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 0.1;   // 0.1 between each tick (grid cross Y axis horizontaly)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        // Secondary Y Axis grid definition. Dot line
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.Dot;

        // Chart Area back ground color
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].BackColor = Color.Black;

        // Create two new functions series
        chart.Series.Add("MyFunc");
        chart.Series.Add("MyFunc2");
        // Set the type to line      
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;

        // Value tooltip on each series
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].ToolTip = "#VAL";
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].ToolTip = "#VAL";

        // Color the line of the graph light green and give it a thickness of 3
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].Color = Color.LightGreen;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].Color = Color.Bisque;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].BorderWidth = 3;

        // Data type definition for the two series (define X and Y axis for each series)
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].XValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].YValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.Double;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].XAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].YAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].XValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].YValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.Double;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].XAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Primary;
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].YAxisType = Graph.AxisType.Secondary;

        //This function cannot include zero, and we walk through it in steps of 0.1 to add coordinates to our series
        DateTime dto;
        dto = new DateTime();
        for (double x = 0.1; x < 20; x += 0.1)
        {
            chart.Series["MyFunc"].Points.AddXY(dto, Math.Sin(x) / x);
            chart.Series["MyFunc2"].Points.AddXY(dto, Math.Cos(x) / x);
            dto = dto.AddSeconds(1);
        }

        // Add legend to the chart area
        chart.Series["MyFunc"].LegendText = "sin(x) / x";
        chart.Series["MyFunc2"].LegendText = "cos(x) / x";

        // Create a new legend called "MyLegend".
        chart.Legends.Add("MyLegend");
        chart.Legends["MyLegend"].BorderColor = Color.Tomato; // I like tomato juice!

        // Zoom allowed for X and Y axis (done manualy on secondary Y axis)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        // X and Y axis cursor definition. 
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IntervalOffsetType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].CursorY.Interval = 0.001D;  // Minimum value for zooming

        // Définition des mises à l'échelles et des barres de défilements axe X et Y
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;

        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSize = 0.1D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0.001D;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

        // Scrollbar color definition
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightBlue;

        // Add the chart to the form (to display it)
        Controls.Add(this.chart);

        // For save and use in AxisViewChanged event
        MaxY2 = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Maximum;
        MinY2 = chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum;

        // Add event handler on axis view changed (to automatically scroll Y and Y2 axis)
        chart.AxisViewChanged += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ViewEventArgs>(chart_AxisViewChanged);
    }

    private void chart_AxisViewChanged(object sender, Graph.ViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum is the minimum Y axis value displayed. It contains the offset to apply to label, grid and interval on Y axis
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Interval;

        // To compute zoom percent to apply on secondary Y axis :
        // zoomPercent = (Max - Min displayed values) / ( Max - Min Y axis values)
        double zoomPercent = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) / 
                             (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum);
        // To compute the position in percent on Y axis
        // posPercent = (Min displayed value - Min value) / ( Max - Min Y axis values)
        double posPercent = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum) / (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Maximum - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.Minimum);

        // To compute max and min secondary axis value regarding posPercent and zoomPercent
        // We need to have the original Max and Min value for secondary Y axis. This should be saved somewhere (MaxY2 and MinY2 here).
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum = (posPercent * (MaxY2 - MinY2)) + MinY2;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Maximum = (zoomPercent * (MaxY2 - MinY2)) + chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum;

        // To update secondary Y axis label, major grid and interval. (same method as for Y axis above)
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Interval;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.IntervalOffset = (chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Interval - chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Minimum) % chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY2.Interval;
    }
```

This solve my problem.
Nevertheless it is a very complicated solution (and certainly time consuming)!

Does someone have another solution ?